# Split files by line content

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file with the following content.

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
1111
qqqq
1111
aaaa
dddd
```

Split into multiple small files with 1111 as a separator.The method I tried is as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while read line  
do
        if [[ $line =~ '1111'  ]];then
                ((i++))
        else
                echo $line >> $i.txt
        fi
done < data.txt
```

Split into several files as follows

```
0.txt
aaaa
bbbb
cccc

1.txt
qqqq

2.txt
aaaa
dddd
```

But I want to get a more concise method, what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

There is a utility built just for this.  Try:

```
csplit -f '' -b'%d.txt' --suppress-matched data.txt /1111/ '{*}'
```

How it works:

- `-f '' -b'%d.txt'`

  These two options tell `csplit` to name the output files with single digits and `.txt` at the end.
- `--suppress-matched`

  This tells `csplit` to omit the divider lines.
- `data.txt`

  This is the file to divide up.
- `/1111/`

  This is the regex pattern to use as a divider.
- `{*}`

  This tells `csplit` to divide as many times as it finds a divider line.

Comment: This gets all but the naming of the output files right?

Comment: @tink You mean the `.txt` at the end?  Good point.  I just fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
awk 'BEGIN{num=0} /^1111/{num++} !/^1111/{print $0 >> num".txt"}' wantianye
```

I named the input file after your username, and it does what you ask with your sample data

```
awk 'BEGIN{num=0}                # initialise num to 0
/^1111/{num++}                   # if the line begins with 1111, increment num
!/^1111/{print $0 >> num".txt"}  # if the line DOESN'T begin with 1111, print it to num'.txt'
' wantianye
```